# JAVA COMPILER API - Cannot finding external class file

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, java-compiler-api

I have a simple code to make Java code compiler

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.tools.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Compiler extends JFrame
{
    String loc="D:\\java";
    File file=null,
         dir=null;
    boolean success;
    public Compiler()
    {
        super("Highlight example");
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } 
        catch (Exception evt) {}
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        JTextArea debug=new JTextArea();
        JButton comp=new JButton("Compile"),
                browse=new JButton("...");

        JTextArea location=new JTextArea();

        JPanel right=new JPanel(),
               up=new JPanel();

        up.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        up.add(new JScrollPane(location),"Center");
        up.add(browse,"East");

        right.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2,1));
        right.add(up,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        right.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), "Center");
        right.add(comp,"South");
        add(right);
        add(new JScrollPane(debug));
        setSize(800, 400);
        setVisible(true);

        browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                success=false;
                UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(loc);
                int status = fc.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
                if (status==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                    debug.setText("");
                    file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    dir = fc.getCurrentDirectory();
                    try
                    {
                        textPane.read(new FileReader(file), null);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        comp.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                    {   
                        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
                        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
                        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
                        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(file+""));
                        String[] option=new String[]{"-g","-parameters"};
                        Iterable<String> options = Arrays.asList(option);
                        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task=null;

                        fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(dir));

                        task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, options, null, compilationUnits);
                        success = task.call();

                        fileManager.close();
                 //     System.out.println("Success: " + success);
                        if(success==true)
                        {
                            debug.setText("Success");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int i=1;
                            for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics())
                                if(diagnostic.getLineNumber()!=-1)
                                    debug.append("Error on line "+diagnostic.getLineNumber()+" in "+ diagnostic+"\n");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Compiler();
    }
}
```

I don't know why compiler can not find previous result of code before. And I have no idea how to fix that.

For more details, I made an example :

1. select A.java
   [image: select A.java]
2. Content of A.java
   [image: result A]
3. then I have select B.java. look A.java has been compiled with create A.class
   [image]
4. B.java can not compile because it can not find `class A`
   [image]

And also can not find class inside package folder.

Here is example 2:

[image]

`A.java` has been compiled with create folder `<path>\a\b`

[image]

and access class using import

[image]

I have some try

from :

```
fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(dir));
```

to :

```
fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, Arrays.asList(dir));
```

but it's not working

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from your pictures where those files live.  Do they *both* live in this `example` folder or do they live in some folder structure `a/b`?

Comment: @Makoto java file inside `example` folder, class file inside structure `a/b` folder if they are contains package.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting `javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT`, you need to set `javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH` to include the same location where you put the previous output:

```
fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(dir));
// Set dirClassPath to include dir, and optionally other locations
fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, Arrays.asList(dirClassPath));
```

Comment: i think it doesn't work if A.java using package, and B using import, post updated.

Comment: @newbie You are not importing it correctly. It should be `import a.b.*;`

Comment: @newbie It does not look like the compiler sees that change (the error message still shows no asterisk after `b`).

Comment: @newbie That's odd. I assume that `a/b/` directory contains `A.class`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the sourcepath directory,
your code

`String[] option=new String[]{"-g","-parameters"};`,

try this

`String[] option=new String[]{"-g","-sourcepath", loc};`

where `loc` is the root directory for the `B` class. With `A` properly stored inside its own package.

I've tried your code, with my modification
http://kurungkurawal.com/gifs/tut-compile.gif

Answer (score 0):

Create jar File of external classes and attach with compiler.

```
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // set compiler's classpath to be same as the runtime's
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path")
                + getValueFromPropertieFile("jarfile1;jarfile2")));

JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, optionList, null,
                compilationUnit);
```